# How do I deal with a function of a neural network?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm a novice for deep learning, and I use keras with tensorflow backend.

Anyway, I have a training set with *N* inputs and outputs (*x_i, y_i*). My model first construct a neural network, say *F*, then use a function *g* to get *y*. In other words, *y=g(F(x))* where *F* is a neural network and *g* is a function, possibly not invertible.

Is there a way to construct such model using keras? To simplify, let *y=3xF(x)+x*. I want to train such model without change training outputs like *(y_i-x_i)/(3x_i)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can using the Keras functional API to define your model and using the Keras backend to call functions to multiply tensors. Make sure that x and F(x) are of the same shape so that you can multiply them. You might to define Lambda layers to ensure that your output is a Keras layer.

For example lets say our function F(x) = Sin((x-1)^2); and we want to calculate x*F(x)+x

Define:

```
from keras.layers import Input,Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

def custom_function(x):
    return K.sin((x-1)*(x-1))+x



def create_model(shape=(10,10,10)):
    x=Input(shape)
    logits=Lambda(custom_function)(x)
    logits= keras.layers.multiply([x,logits])
    logits = keras.layers.add([logits,x])
    model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=logits)
    return model
```

All you need to do is to ensure that the shapes are consistent so that we can add them and multiply them.

For some more info on the functional API look at this: https://keras.io/models/model/

Comment: Is it possible to use a custom function g instead of addition and multiplication?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to be able to define the function G with keras backend or tensorflow ops

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you!

Comment: I think 3*x*logits+x is not supported because the result is not a layer. Instead, we should use 
keras.layers.Add()
keras.layers.Multiply()
please check this.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a layer; in the functional API you just manipulate tensors with TF ops. The issue can be that shapes don't work out as I pointed out. You can't multiply x with f(x) unless they are of the same shape

Comment: An error occurs when set Model(inputs=x, outputs=logits)

Comment: Well, I found Lambda in keras API. keras.layers.lambda will resolve this!

Comment: Yes, you're right we can't have pure TF tensors as the output . For this we need to use Keras layers add and multiply and not just treat them as pure TF tensors. Updated the code; checked that it works now